# WPF Datatemplate control not getting public property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf application in which i change the itemtemplate of a listview on runtime. The item template is based on different usercontrols that have a public property:

```
    private bool _checkdb = false;
    public bool CheckDB
    {
        get { return _checkdb; }
        set { _checkdb = value; }
    }
```

My xaml is the following:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT_Main">
        <local:UC_ViewMain CheckDB="True" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT_Simple"  >
        <local:UC_ViewSimple CheckDB="True"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT_Detailed" >
        <local:UC_ViewDetailed CheckDB="True" />
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now when i change the itemtemplate for the listview, the property CheckDB is always false. The code to change the itemtemplate is the following:

```
listBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DT_Main"];
```

So every time the CheckDB property is false instead of true. Is there anyway i could implement this in order to set the value from the Xaml? I would like to check this value when the Usercontrol is either Loaded or it's Datacontext changes.

Thanks

Comment: "So every time the CheckDB property is false instead of true". Where do you access the property value? If it's in the UserControl's constructor, it is not yet set.

Comment: The problem is that i was checking the CheckDB on the Datacontext changed event and there it was always false. After changing to the loaded event, everything worked properly. I guess the Property is not Loaded before the control is Loaded and the Datacontext event fires even when the control is not loaded.